# TCP/IPv6 thru ssh tunnel

Tags: linux, ssh, ipv6

i am wondering how to tunnel tcp/ipv6 traffic over the ssh/ipv4 tunnel (ptp connection). Is it possible? How can i achieve that?

Comment: Are you trying to tunnel JUST ipV6 traffic over the tunnel? As your SSH tunnel will allow you to use IPV5 or V6 over it without issue, assuming the network at either ends support it.

Comment: TCP over TCP is usually not a good idea: http://sites.inka.de/sites/bigred/devel/tcp-tcp.html TCP over TCP over TCP: It doesn't sound any better

Answer (score 16):

Yes, it is possible and not too difficult, but the solution is very suboptimal, since SSH runs over TCP and has a sensible overhead.

The server must have in its configuration file `sshd_config`:

```
PermitTunnel point-to-point
```

Then, you need to be root on **both** machines. You connect to the server using:

```
ssh -w any root@server
```

After connection, use the command `ip link` in both systems to know which **tunN** device was created in each one, and use it in the following commands. Note that I'm using example site-local addresses, which are obsolete, but ok for this introduction.

On the server:

```
server# ip link set tun0 up
server# ip addr add fec0:1::1/112 dev tun0
```

On the client:

```
client# ip link set tun0 up
client# ip addr add fec0:1::2/112 dev tun0
```

This is enough so that you can ping the other side through the tunnel, if there is no firewall rule blocking. The next step is to set routes over the tunnel (don't forget net.ipv6.conf.default.forwarding=1), and then adjust the link MTU to get optimal performance.

```
server# sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1

client# ip -6 route add default via fec0:1::1
```

This will allow your client to ping other networks that the server has access to, given that the targets have routes back to your remote client.

You'll also have to fix the link MTU so that the client doesn't send packets that the server won't be able to transmit forward. This depends on the MTU of the IPv6 link of the server itself. Do not rely on path MTU discovery since it won't work correctly over the SSH tunnel. If in doubt, start with a low MTU value, like 1280 (minimum MTU allowed for IPv6).

Comment: The minimum MTU that IPv6 supports is 1280 (in contrast to IPv4, which supports a minimum MTU of 576). Warning: if you set your MTU below 1280, your IPv6 addresses will disappear, and won’t be able to be re-added until you restart SSH!

Comment: OS X doesn't have the `ip` command, so set the ip address with

    `sudo ifconfig tun0 inet6 fec0:1::2/112 up`

and set the route with

    `sudo route add -inet6 -mtu 1280 default fec0:1::1`